Are there any good books for studying auxiliary skills or generally useful tools?
By "auxiliary skills," I'm referring to a book like J. Michael Steele's The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class, which focuses on the specific study of inequalities—something fundamental and useful everywhere. Does anyone know of other books like this for different skills or topics?
I'm an undergrad just starting out with advanced mathematics, so books/resources like this would be very helpful for me.
P.S. I suppose "intro to proofs" books would work as an answer, but I'm looking for books primarily focused on a skill/toolset like in my example.

Yaglom’s Transformations comes to mind

not a book, but Terry Tao’s blog has lots of such cool insights spread out over various articles. Find one that interests you.
